# Filtering a simple list data source?

Tags: 2010, list, filter, xslt-list-view-web-part

I'm using SharePoint Designer for SharePoint 2010.

I created a new site page.  On this page, I added a simple DataView via the designer (XsltListViewWebPart) that pulls all items from a list in the same site.

Now, I need to modify that DataSource to only pull items from the list where the "Approver" field in that list is the current running user.  So, my first thought was to set a filter for the [Current User].

However, I don't see any options for filtering this DataSource based off a field?  The "Current Data Source" in the "Data Source Details" pane is grayed out.

How do I filter a simple DataSource like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good grief, adding basic data should not be this confusing.  By inserting the data view two different ways, I had two different results with missing options.

One way that I added the data view resulted in a Xslt List View Web Part, another way resulted in a Data Form Web Part.

The options for filtering would never show with the Xslt List View.  The working way in SPD:

> Insert -> Data View -> Empty Data View -> Choose a list

If you do:

> Insert -> Data View -> Lists -> Choose a list

The result is a different control.